# How to convert MASConstraint to NSLayoutConstraint?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am currently using "Masonry" and "POP" in my app. I am wondering how to animate the constraint created by Masonry?
So Here's my code:

```
[imageView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.size.equalTo([NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight)]);
        make.top.equalTo(self.mas_top);
    }];
```

So it's a simple example. When POP is animating the change of constraint it needs something like this (I am saving some codes here):

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *containerHeightConstraint;
[self.containerHeightConstraint pop_addAnimation:spring forKey:@"spring"];
```

I have no problem getting these two library working separately but I am wondering how to animate the change of MASConstraint because POP need to take an NSLayoutConstraint as parameter as it stated in the documentation. So the question here is how to convert MASConstraint to NSLayoutConstraint? Can anyone please help?

Comment: I also need this.  Masonry is great but sometimes external libraries need access to the raw NSLayoutConstraint.

Comment: So do you have any solution? I ended up using NSLayoutConstraint for that specific constraint that needs to be changed

Answer (score 3):

`MASConstraint` is an abstract class and can potentially represent not one but several `NSLayoutConstraints` at once, so it's not quite applicable to get a reference as one would expect.

That being said, you can use MASConstraint's `setOffset`: method to modify underlying NSLayoutConstraint's layout constant which satisfies many animation use cases. As shown below:

```
MASConstraint *widthConstraint;
[POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:@"offset"];
animation.springBounciness = 8;
[widthConstraint pop_addAnimation:animation forKey:@"myAnimation"];
```

Searching for any alternative I came across [this thread](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry/issues/94) with replies from the author himself on a similar issue.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the help! It looks good. Although I asked this question quite a while ago. I'll definite refer to it when I need this

Answer (score 0):

See the 'MSSPopMasonry' on github

A lib Use Masonry with the Facebook Pop animation framework

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I am looking for a way to resolve this issue rather than adding one more dependency

Comment: why did someone downvote this post, it can solve the question, and it's just THE WAY to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice tool which has combined pop and Masonry, which is called MSSPopMasonry: https://github.com/miklselsoe/MSSPopMasonry. With it (only 2 source files) you can make pop animations on MASContraint, so you don't need to convert MASContraint to NSLayoutConstraint which is not supported in Masonry. The usage is simple:

```
// declare the constraint you want to animate with
MASConstraint *_signInScreenLeadingConstraint;
BOOL _isInSignUpScreen = NO;

// set constraint using Masonry
[view mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    _signInScreenLeadingConstraint = make.left.equalTo(view.superview).with.offset(0);
    make.top.and.bottom.equalTo(view.superview).with.offset(0);
    make.width.equalTo(view.superview).with.offset(0);
}];

// animate by pop
POPBasicAnimation *exchangeAnimation = [POPBasicAnimation easeInAnimation];
exchangeAnimation.property = [POPAnimatableProperty mas_offsetProperty];
exchangeAnimation.duration = 0.2f;
exchangeAnimation.toValue = _isInSignUpScreen ? @(0) : @(200);
[exchangeAnimation setCompletionBlock:^(POPAnimation *anim, BOOL finished) {
    _isInSignUpScreen = !_isInSignUpScreen;
}];
[_signInScreenLeadingConstraint pop_addAnimation:exchangeAnimation forKey:@"animation"];
```

Thanks to the author of MSSPopMasonry:)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's a great solution! However, I'm just a little bit hesitated about adding one more dependencies.

Comment: MSSPopMasonry has just one source file and two head files, you can go through the source and see how does the author do, then you can write subset logics to meet your requirement.

Comment: Oh. That sounds nice. I didn't look at the source code before. I'll definitely refer to his answer when I come across this problem next time. Thanks for the help!